# Jenkins - trigger chain of builds with job names as parameter

Tags: python, groovy, jenkins

I want some experienced advice here...

I want to accept as a parameter a list of job names (comma or space delimited string).

Jenkins needs to build them as a chain, one after the other, in the order they were entered (I validate the list before triggering them). The list length is unknown.

Please suggest possible solutions (I'm considering groovy script, shell with curl and Jason calls or maybe python).

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to go with a groovy script executed with a groovy build step. It works well aside for a major issue I have with lost parameters as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279148/jenkins-groovy-build-step-trigger-another-job-in-groovy-script-removes-original) I posted.

Any help is more than welcome.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, put your jobs list in your_jobs_lists.txt, per jobname each line.
**Second**, `pip install python-jenkins` to install the python wrapper for jenkins REST API. Then use below python script to run your jobs.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import jenkins
jenkins_url = "http://your_jenkins_server_url/"
username = "youruserid"
token = "yourToken"
j = jenkins.Jenkins(jenkins_url, username=username, password=token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fp = open("your_jobs_lists.txt", "r")
    alllines = fp.readlines()
    for jobname in alllines:
        jobname = jobname.strip('\n')
        j.build_job(jobname,{'param1': 'test value 1', 'param2': 'test value 2'},{'token': token})            
        time.sleep(3)
    print "Done!"
```

For those who don't know where to find the token, here is how:

> login to jenkins -> click your userid from the top of the webpage ->
>   Configure ->Show API Token...

Enjoy it.