# Jenkins groovy build step trigger another job in groovy script removes original job's parameters

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I'm using a groovy script to trigger other jobs, which is based on the example from the [Groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) page.

I get a list of jobs as a parameter, validate they exist and trigger them with a few parameters. See main trigger code:

```
    // Prepare parameters array
    def params = 
    [
        new StringParameterValue('PARAM1', 'val1'),
        new StringParameterValue('PARAM2', 'val2'),
    ]
    def future = job.scheduleBuild2(0, new Cause.UpstreamCause(build), new ParametersAction(params))
    println "Waiting for the completion of " + jobLink
    anotherBuild = future.get()
```

My triggered jobs run perfectly, but with one **major** problem. Their original parameters are lost and are replaced by the new ones **PARAM1** and **PARAM2**.

How to I trigger a job and **add** to its default parameters and **not replace** them?

I tried hard to find a solution for it and didn't find one...

**EDIT:** I was thinking of not setting parameters (and allowing job to use its defaults), but setting environment variables for the job's execution. Does anyone have an idea or example on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying many options, I decided to load the default parameters for the job I'm about to trigger and add them to the parameter array I'm preparing as in the example below.

I used the example from [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Display+job+parameters) to get my job's initial default configuration.

I still has to add some logic to choices parameters and null values, but I'm happy with the current result.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Do you know a way to just "include" the build steps ie performing in the current build, rather kicking off a separate one? (similar to the Template plugin, but from script https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin )

Comment: No, I have no idea... but why do you want to do this?

Comment: I wanted to create sort of a "proxy" job,that behave like others on demand.E.g have a long-running unit test suite - but I also one to run single tests from time to time, controlled by parameter.However I don't wanna pollute the build history of the standard test job, instead have a custom-test one -where I can try things quickly on the server (without have to set up things locally, eg for a particular version). In this custom-test job I want do exactly the same thing as for the standard job, just trim down the test suite via a parameter.So,reuse same job build steps,but keep history separate.

Comment: BTW, I have figure this out using Groovy, it works great. I can post if anyone is interested.

Comment: Don't ask... post it! :-) It's an interesting idea that might be very useful in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

These days I would use something like [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) for this.
That orchestration DSL/API reduces the code in question to:

```
 build('job', PARAM1: 'val1'
              PARAM2: 'val2')
```

You can pass the params as hash map, the ones that are missing will fall back to the default values.

One issue with this plugin: it may be abandoned soon.
A brand new alternative(not released yet): https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin.